# Different number of nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

Currently I have the following problem.

On the one hand, there is a variable number of lists with strings as elements, on the other hand there are variations in which the individual elements of the lists are need to be linked.

Each element from one list should be combined with each element from another list according to the specification of `list_order`. You get `list_result`. If you know how many lists there are, then you solve it with nested for loops. But how do I get it done if the number of lists varies?
I also tried recursion, but it did not work.

```
list_a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list_b = ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
list_c = ['1', '2']

list_order = [['list_a', 'list_b', 'list_c'], ['list_b', 'list_c']]

list_result = [['AH1', 'AH2', 'AI1', 'AI2', ...], ['H1', 'H2', 'I1', 'I2', ...]]
```

Comment: why are you using the variable names as string literals? You might need a dict just to get to the data. It sounds like you eventually want to get to itertools, and then you can just concatenate the strings.

Comment: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product as pd
list_result = [[''.join(k) for k in pd(*[eval(i) for i in j])] for j in list_order]
print(list_result)
```

**Output**

```
[['AH1', 'AH2', 'AI1', 'AI2', 'AJ1', 'AJ2', 'AK1', 'AK2', 'AL1', 'AL2', 'BH1', 'BH2', 'BI1', 'BI2', 'BJ1', 'BJ2', 'BK1', 'BK2', 'BL1', 'BL2', 'CH1', 'CH2', 'CI1', 'CI2', 'CJ1', 'CJ2', 'CK1', 'CK2', 'CL1', 'CL2'], ['H1', 'H2', 'I1', 'I2', 'J1', 'J2', 'K1', 'K2', 'L1', 'L2']]
```

Comment: you @user10987432 that's what I thought and it works both, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the `list_order` to represent indecies to the lists.

```
from itertools import product

list_a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list_b = ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
list_c = ['1', '2']

lists = [list_a, list_b, list_c]

list_order = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2]]

for order in list_order:
    current_lists = [lists[index] for index in order]
    for tpl in product(*current_lists):
        print("".join(tpl))
```

Comment: you and @Vicrobot so I thought so and it works both, thanks :)